# Ubuntu cannot detect my external hard drive. But another OS on the same PC can detect and access the external HDD

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, 22.04, external-hdd

Here is dmesg output that tells what's the error -

```
[ 3221.289446] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[ 3221.417388] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3221.657542] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3221.893443] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[ 3222.021501] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3222.257549] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 3222.365671] usb usb3-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 3223.021424] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[ 3223.021737] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3223.229603] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3223.437368] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 40, error -71
[ 3223.565447] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[ 3223.565739] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3223.773731] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 3223.981362] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 41, error -71
[ 3223.981595] usb usb3-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Here's the output of `lsblk` -

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0 271.4M  1 loop /snap/brave/195
loop2         7:2    0 270.1M  1 loop /snap/brave/196
loop3         7:3    0  27.1M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/28
loop4         7:4    0  18.4M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/30
loop5         7:5    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2654
loop6         7:6    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2667
loop7         7:7    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1738
loop8         7:8    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1778
loop9         7:9    0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/469
loop10        7:10   0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/484
loop11        7:11   0  16.2M  1 loop /snap/foliate/1167
loop12        7:12   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop13        7:13   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop14        7:14   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
loop15        7:15   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop16        7:16   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop17        7:17   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop18        7:18   0  37.1M  1 loop /snap/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004/2
loop19        7:19   0   180M  1 loop /snap/opera/216
loop20        7:20   0   180M  1 loop /snap/opera/215
loop21        7:21   0 187.6M  1 loop /snap/postman/183
loop22        7:22   0 188.3M  1 loop /snap/postman/184
loop23        7:23   0 112.6M  1 loop /snap/slack/67
loop24        7:24   0 115.8M  1 loop /snap/slack/68
loop25        7:25   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599
loop26        7:26   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop27        7:27   0  49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
loop28        7:28   0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17950
loop29        7:29   0   304K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/43
loop30        7:30   0   304K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49
loop31        7:31   0 169.4M  1 loop /snap/spotify/60
loop32        7:32   0 375.1M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/4470
loop33        7:33   0 375.1M  1 loop /snap/telegram-desktop/4486
loop34        7:34   0 295.7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop35        7:35   0 320.4M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3078
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  99.3G  0 part /media/soumyanil/Windows
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   862M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   100G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0 275.9G  0 part /media/soumyanil/New Volume
└─nvme0n1p7 259:7    0   585M  0 part
```

How can I solve this issue ?

P.S. - Ubuntu version is 22.04. The HDD is WD 1 TB. Model No. - WD10JPVX

Comment: You need to provide more information about the type, brand, connection type, etc. of the external drive. What is the output of `lsblk` before and after you attach the drive? Please [edit] your question to add the extra information.

Comment: Same problem  if you connect your device to an usb2 port?

Comment: @nobody I do not think my laptop has a usb2 port. coz all three usb ports are usb 3-1 , 3-2, 3-3.

Comment: @FedKad if my drive is not being detected, then how will lsblk show information about the hdd. anyways edited the question as you asked.

Comment: `journalctl | grep -i uas` any output?

Comment: @nobody Yes a ton. Basically this thing repeatedly shows up with some `modules linked in` in between - 
`Jan 22 13:25:08 b3s7-fr13nd kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jan 22 16:45:32 b3s7-fr13nd kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jan 22 16:53:54 b3s7-fr13nd kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas`

Comment: Can you boot up the system which recognized your drive and show `lsusb`  maybe a quirk will help.

Comment: @nobody it's windows.

Comment: Oh too bad. No experience with new windows releases.

Comment: You can still mention about the USB device type, brand, model, etc. in your question. If somebody owns a similar device they may be able to help you.

Comment: @FedKad sure. it's an internal hdd turned external one. I'll mention it anyways.

Comment: "device descriptor read/64, error -71" is a hardware error and probably with the connector or the voltage. If the voltage that might make sense for windows to work: windows will run into problems later on during usage and will randomly disable devices to free up power.

Comment: @Rinzwind I see. will changing the usb to usb connector work ? do you have any other fixes in mind ?

Comment: I am not really a hardware guy... just some observations I noticed while using hardware. A power supply might fix it if it is a voltage issue. Some external hard disks need one and some only need power over usb.